# combining two datasets column for column

Tags: r, dataset

many questions have been answered regarding combining datasets but not this. I have two datasets, A and B (In my case before and after a treatment).
"A" contains column "aa"|"ab"|"ac" and "B" contains column "ba"|"bb"|"bc". I want the new dataset to look like this: "new dataset": column "aa"|"ba"|"ab"|"bb"|"ac"|"bc". In other words - I would like different measurments before and after a treatment to appear after each other. This would make it easier to produce for example big boxplot charts.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry I mean by dataset a dataframe, imported from excel.

Comment: Sorry, it´s imported into R

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.